# Length of Parallelogram Diagonals

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I have a problem with vectors.  It is said that there are $2$ vectors $\overrightarrow{m}$  and $\overrightarrow{n}$ with length $1$ and $\angle (m,n)=60^\circ$. $\overrightarrow{a}$ and  $\overrightarrow{b}$ are $2$ vectors such that  $\overrightarrow{a}=2\overrightarrow{m}+\overrightarrow{n}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}=\overrightarrow{m}-2\overrightarrow{n}$ and represent the sides of parallelogram. I have to calculate the length of the diagonals of this parallelogram. Thank you very much!

Comment: Say us where you are blocked.

Comment: I know that m and n forms a equilateral triungle but I don't know how to use it in a and b vectors

Comment: You could just let $m$ be $(1,0)$.  You can always rotate the coordinates to make this so.  What is $n$?  Then compute $a$ and $b$ and the other corner of the parallelogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagonal vectors will be addition and subtraction of these two vectors.
I am calculating one, you can do other one with similar procedure.
[image: Parallelogram law for vector addition.]

You have to calculate length of diagonal i.e. $| \overrightarrow{a}+ \overrightarrow{b}|$

$$| \overrightarrow{a}+ \overrightarrow{b}|= |(2\overrightarrow{m}+\overrightarrow{n}) + (\overrightarrow{m}-2\overrightarrow{n})|=|3\overrightarrow{m}-\overrightarrow{n}|=\sqrt{|3\overrightarrow{m}|^2+|\overrightarrow{n}|^2+2|\overrightarrow{3m}||\overrightarrow{n}| \cos \angle(m,n)}=\sqrt{9+1+6\times \cos 60^\circ}=\sqrt{13}$$

Do the same for other one. (subtract vectors $\overrightarrow{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{b}$ in that case)

Answer (score 0):

A parallelogram with vector "sides" a and b has diagonals $a+b$ and $a-b$.

In this case it means $(2m+n)+(m-2n)=3m-n$ and  $2m+n-(m-2n)=m+3n.$

The square of their lengths is the dot product of these vectors with themselves:

$(3m-n).(3m-n)=9m^2+n^2-6 m.n=9+1-6 \cos(60°)=7$ and

$(m+3n).(m+3n)=m^2+9n^2+6 m.n=1+9+6 \cos(60°)=13.$

It suffices now to take the square roots of these values.